# Return content of helper from controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created a helper named ManagementHeirarchy.

Now after some processing i want to return the results from controller to the the view again to update a particular div.

like we return partialviews as

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Hr/_ReviewersListForSpecifiedJobApplication.cshtml", listCorporateHierarchy);
```

how can we return results from helper?

How can i do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you should just write the name of the partial view instead of writing everything u wrote..

for example if the name of the partial view is "partial.cshtml" then

```
return PartialView("partial",objectName);
```

so in ur case it would be

```
return PartialView("ReviewersListForSpecifiedJobApplication",listCorporateHierarchy);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
return PartialView("ReviewersListForSpecifiedJobApplication",model);
```

where, `model` is the data returned from the helper.

OR

You can save the data from the helper in the `Viewbag` and then use it in the `View` as below:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ReviewersListForSpecifiedJobApplication()
{
   //some helper returning data in "data" variable
   ViewBag.datafromhelper= data;
   return PartialView();
}
```

If you don't have separate method for returning the View then just pass the view name only as below:

```
 return PartialView("ReviewersListForSpecifiedJobApplication");
```

Comment: how would we use helper in this controller method, that is my question.

Comment: @user1960365 Show your helper code. or how you are calling it?